# Getting values for a 4 dimensional array through a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, web

In my website, I have a scenario in which I need to get user input values for 1,2,3 and 4 dimensional array.

I couldn't find any UI related help on what should I display to the user and get different value for the array.

For example, for 2 dimensional array you can just display a matrix. But I am trying display something visually similar to the user for 3 and 4 dimensional array.

Comment: Why can't you just show it like JSON does?

Comment: You mean to add the whole lengthy column for all the indexes like [1,2,3,2] and having a input field corresponding to every row ?

Comment: Use a `<textarea>`

Comment: Can you show me an example with snapshot or some website link ?

Comment: This question is way too broad and will be opinion based. It is not for stack overflow, and has little to do with the tagged technologies. UI or UX design should be discussed at the expert sites.

Comment: why not then where should I ask this questions ?

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha somewhere where there are UI/UX experts who can tell you how your data input should be done. For reference on how to ask a good question on SO you can see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, Vladmir, But I don't have a better place to ask this question.

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha its up to you. All I am saying is that you may spend your time here and not get the answer you are looking for (for many reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<textarea>`

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");

var data = JSON.parse(input.value);

console.log(data[0][1][1]);
```

```css
textarea {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
[
  [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]],
  [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]],
  [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
]
</textarea>
```